# How to show information of specific beer inside a beercase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an application where it has beer, beercase, and drinker models on it. The beer inside the beercase can be assorted.

I'm bit struggling in how to show the information of a specific beer inside a beer case. Currently I listed all the beers inside the beercase of the drinker so I have a list of beer partial _beerlist:

```
<h1>beer you added</h1>
<% @drinker.beercase_line_items.each do |beer|%>
<p><%= link_to beer.beer.name, specificbeer_drinker_drinker_beercase_pages_path(@drinker) %></p>
<%end%>
```

I tried doing this but

```
<h1>beer you added</h1>
<% @drinker.beercase_line_items.each do |beer|%>
<p><%= link_to beer.beer.name, specificbeer_drinker_drinker_beercase_pages_path(@drinker,beer) %></p>
<%end%>
```

gives me a `beer.20` at the middle of the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator), not `beer/20` which I wanted for him to produce. Am I doing this right?

**routes**

```
resources :drinker do
    resources :pages do
        collection do
            get :beercaselist # Name of beercase that can be added example:extrabucket-beercase
            get :beercase # Show the beercase information and it has a link to add beer
        end
    end
        resources :drinker_beercase # Controller to add what beercase that the drinker added
            resources :drinker_beercase_pages do # Static page controller
                collection do
                    get :beerlist # Show the beerlist
                    get :specificbeer # Show the specificbeer
                end
            end
        resources :beercase_line_items # Controller to add what beer and what beercase
end
```

Comment: Your code makes me thirsty ;-)

Comment: Could you post your routes file and perhaps the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: @jeffSmith:routes added i just added comments cause you might get confuse with my naming convention thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so bear with me, I don't think I fully understand your routes, but I think this may be your problem:

Your `specificbeer_drinker_drinker_beercase_pages` route looks like this:

```
/drinker/:drinker_id/drinker_beercase_pages/specificbeer(.:format)
```

That only has the `:drinker_id` parameter in it.  This route is meant for displaying a list of specificbeers, not a single specific beer.  If you change your routes file to look like this:

```
resources :drinker_beercase # controller to add what beercase that the drinker added 
  resources :drinker_beercase_pages do #static page controller
    collection do
      get :beerlist # show the beerlist
    end
    member do
      get :specificbeer # show the specificbeer
    end
  end
end
```

Then the `specificbeer_drinker_drinker_beercase_page` will lead to this url:

```
/drinker/:drinker_id/drinker_beercase_pages/:id/specificbeer(.:format)
```

I'm not sure exactly if that's what you're going for, but hopefully it helps lead you in the right direction.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply i solve my problem by changing this
`<p><%= link_to beer.beer.name, specificbeer_drinker_drinker_beercase_pages_path(@drinker,beer) %></p>` to this 
`<p><%= link_to beer.beer.name, specificbeer_drinker_drinker_beercase_pages_path(@drinker,:beer_id => beer.beer_id) %></p>` im not sure if i did it right but i gives me what i wanted to which is to pass the beer id that was clicked and show its infromation ill try also your post